# How to initialize nested list Capacities?

Tags: c#, list

I want to make a list of lists in C#, the outer list must have a capacity of 5 and each inner a capacity of 100. How to initialize it ?

This code does not compile:

```
List<List<int>> outer = new List<List<int>>(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    outer[i].Add(new List<int>(100));
}
```

Edit: I didn't want the lists to change size on runtime, cause memory allocation destroys performance and this is for a mobile game

Comment: Lists don't have a capacity, and they don't need to be initialized.

Comment: That actually creates exactly what you ask for. Perhaps the problem is that you expect that setting the capacity would create items?

Comment: @Guffa this code does not compile

Comment: @roryap: Lists do actually have a capacity.

Comment: @roryap https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a minor typo.

```
List<List<int>> outer = new List<List<int>>(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      // vv here //
    outer[i].Add(new List<int>(100));
}
```

You're trying to add the list to itself, which, of course, doesn't work. If you drop that `[i]`, that should solve your problem.

```
List<List<int>> outer = new List<List<int>>(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    outer.Add(new List<int>(100));
}
```

---

That said, if you don't have a strict need for the outer capacity to be set, I'd suggest doing this with LINQ.

```
List<List<int>> outer = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(c => new List<int>(100)).ToList();
```

And if you do need a capacity, an array might be a better fit for the outer collection.

Comment: i do have a strict need for capacities, both outter and inner. does the answer you provided ensure that the lists have a capacity of  5 and 100 ?

Comment: @Shiro Yeah, the stuff above the line does.

Comment: oh you said the outer collection to be array ? you are right, thank you for the tip

Comment: what is the difference of the linq code you provided with the code above it ? it looks identical to me, is it not ?

Comment: @Shiro The only difference is that the LINQ doesn't set the capacity of the outer list. The reason I say I would go with it is because it's just a bit cleaner, but you're right that it does turn out the same result, aside from that.